# Undefined variable: transaction_id(View: resources/views/view_all_transaction.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

How can i define transaction_id or initialize transaction_id in my laravel  code i am stuck .

this the code on AdminContoller.php

```
 public function provetransaction(Request $req, $transaction_id)
    {

        $transaction_id = transaction::find ($req->transaction_id);
        $provetransaction = \DB::table('transaction')->where('transaction_id', $transaction_id)->first();
        return view('provetransaction', compact('amount_paid', 'transaction_id'));
    }
    public function updateprove(Request $request, $transaction_id)
    {
        switch($request->get('approve'))
        {
            case 0:
                Post::postpone($transaction_id);
                break;
            case 1:
                Post::approve($transaction_id);
                break;
            case 2:
                Post::reject($transaction_id);
                break;
            case 3:
                Post::postpone($transaction_id);
                break;
            default:    
                break;

        }
        return redirect('view_all_transaction');
    }
```

Below is my web.php where i have defined my routes.i have updated i have removed id i have used transaction_id instead.

```
web.php
Route::get('/view_all_transaction', 'AdminController@view_all_transaction')->name('admin');
Route::post('/view_all_transaction/{transaction_id}', 'AdminController@provetransaction')->name('admin');
Route::post('/view_all_transaction', 'AdminController@updateprove')->name('admin');
```

this my view_all_transaction.blade.php where the action is being passed 
so where i am wrong.

```
<td><a href="{{ action('AdminController@provetransaction', $view_all_transaction->transaction_id) }}" class="btn btn-warning">Moderate</a></td> 
       <div id="MyModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <!-- Modal Content: begins -->
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel">Your Headings</h4>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal Body -->  
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="body-message">
          <h4>Approve </h4>
              <div class="container">
      <form method="post" action="action="{{action('AdminController@updateprove', $transaction_id)}}">
        @csrf
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <lable>Approval</lable>
                <select name="approve">
                  <option value="0" @if($view_all_transaction->status==0)selected @endif>Pending</option>
                  <option value="1" @if($view_all_transaction->status==1)selected @endif>Approve</option>
                  <option value="2" @if($view_all_transaction->status==2)selected @endif>Reject</option>
                  <option value="3" @if($view_all_transaction->status==3)selected @endif>Postponed</option> 
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
<!--         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top:40px">Update</button>
                </div>
        </div> -->
      </form>
    </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal Footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
       <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
      <button id="btnPrint" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Approve</button>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Modal Content: ends -->
```

Comment: The error is reported in the view code. Please post the relevant parts of `view_app_transaction.blade.php`  .

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski i have updated my code i have removed `id` and replaced it with `transaction_id` instead

Answer (score 0):

The error is indicating that you used $id in your view code. In order to do so, you should compact a variable called "id" to your view.

Comment: I have change 'id' to 'transaction_id'

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
dd($req->all());
```

And make sure what key are in the request

Comment: ```Undefined variable: transaction_id (0)``` when i ```dd($req->all());```it is giving me the above error